# Prove that each multiple of 4 plus 3 is either prime or divisible by any $n\equiv3(\mod 4)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I've been looking at a couple of questions in revision for an upcoming exam this year, and I've half solved a question, except for this bit.

I need to prove that for every multiple of 4, plus 3 (e.g: 3 x 4 + 3 = 15) is either a prime number or divisible by a number n for $n\equiv3(\mod 4)$

Thanks!

P.S. It's a bit vague, I don't know how to explain it, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $n\equiv3\pmod4$ isn't prime. Consider its divisors. If any are $3\pmod4$, we are done. Otherwise, since $n$ is odd, all its divisors must be $1\pmod4$.

But if you multiply a bunch of numbers that are $1\pmod4$, the result will still be $1\pmod4$. This contradicts $n\equiv3\pmod4$.